# Disable tooltip for Line chart for one line

Tags: charts, chart.js, tooltip, line

I am creating a line chart with multiple lines.  I am trying to disable the tooltip that pops up over one of the lines.  Is it possible to disable the tool top for one of the lines, but not all of them?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting pointRadius and pointHitRadius to 0.

`datasets:[{ data:[...], pointRadius: 0, pointHitRadius:0 }]`

Answer (score 0):

To disable the tooltip for a specific serie / line you can use the follow property:

```
enableMouseTracking: false
```

E.g. to disable the tooltip of the "Serie 2":

```
series: [{
        name: "Serie 1"
        data: [70, 55, 60]
    }, {
        name: "Serie 2"
        data: [45, 25, 40]
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }]
```